# Renderizar HTML guardado en un campo de base de datos SQLServer

Tags: html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tengo HTML guardado como Varchar en una base de datos SQL Server. Estoy intentando insertar este HTML en una view pero al hacerlo, éste se pasa como texto y no como HTML (Osea, al HTML le agrega **comillas dobles** al inicio y al final, lo que no posibilita su renderizado.

El HTML en cuestión lo estoy guardando en un string en mi controlador, el cual es pasado como parámetro a la vista.

**Ya Probé:**

1. HttpUtility.Encode(miHtml)
2. el data annotation [DataType(DataType.HTML)]

Comment: @PabloLozano en realidad es texto con formato (negrita, cursiva, etc...) que para renderizar en la web necesita html (al menos en la forma que conozco)

Comment: Me refería a usar "estoreado" en lugar de "guardado" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por default [Razor codifica las cadenas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) por esta razon no puedes directamente incrustar el texto como HTML. Es por una razon de seguridad... imaginate escribir codigo scripting "sin quererlo"

Para poder escribir HTML en crudo, existe el helper [.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg480740.aspx)

Ejemplo

```
@Html.Raw("<span>StarWars!</span>")
```

En tu caso

```
 @Html.Raw(miHtml)
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Metodo HtmlHelper.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg480740.aspx)
- [Sintaxis Razor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia.

Comment: Cierto Jose! Había olvidado ese Helper. Funcionó de maravilla, gracias!